# Lightning - centering the grid to the middle & the fixing column width

Tags: lightning, lightning-design-system

[image]I am learning lightning and stuck with centering the grid to the center of the page.

```
 <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-gutters slds-align_absolute-center 
  slds-grid--pull-padded">
    <div class="slds-size_1-of-2"> A </div> 
    <div class="slds-size_1-of-2"> B </div> 
 </div>
```

For brevity,I have not typed the text boxes in place of A,B.

1. How can I center the whole grid so that columns appear centered rather than left aligned?
2. How can I fix the width of the text boxes to my choice(reduce)
   Seems like a simple solution but have been spending a lot of time, please help.

I tried <center&rt; & 'slds-align_absolute-center' to no avail :(

Answer (score 1):

To minimize the effort, you can actually specify

> slds-align_absolute-center

on each of your divs, this should center them both in your grid.

```
 <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-gutters slds-grid--pull-padded">
    <div class="slds-size_1-of-2 slds-align_absolute-center slds-theme_success"> A </div> 
    <div class="slds-size_1-of-2 slds-align_absolute-center slds-theme_warning"> B </div> 
 </div>
```

[image]

added some slds-themes for visibilities sake, feel free to remove it.

Comment: glls, Thank you..will try this, how to fix the column width? I want them reduced.

Comment: several  ways, you can add padding, or set a predefined width, easiest option might be adding some padding between the elements

Comment: glls, The solution proposed of using 'slds-align_absolute-center' did not work. The issue I am facing is that some rows are going to be empty on one side and using this approach the alignment on the left of the form components is not proper. Also, there is a large gap between the controls and the controls appear to be far reduced than what I wanted. I have added a screenshot for your ref.

Comment: im affraid there is no immediate solution then, you will have to CSS the s*** out of your page to get the specific behavior. Additionally, as mentioned prior, you can set the width in different ways, I would suggest you start ramping up those CSS skills